# Uncaught (in promise): Error: Could not load \"marker\"

Tags: angular, google-maps, angular-google-maps

I'm using the [Angular Google Maps](https://angular-maps.com/api-docs/agm-core/index.html) package and sometimes I have a few error logs from clients who, apparently, cannot load certain elements -like, in this example, the markers-. I can't reproduce the error in a development environment. My question is not really how to solve the error (maybe the resource is just not available) but how could I catch that exception so that I can handle it gracefully.

```
Uncaught (in promise): Error: Could not load \"marker\".

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&callback=agmLazyMapsAPILoader&key=xxx&libraries=places:82:241
P@https://www.my-website.com/polyfills.e7eccfefd953dba9834b.js:1:19546
onInvokeTask@https://www.my-website.com/vendor.19003f536e32efb3f8e2.js:1:319734
runTask@https://www.my-website.com/polyfills.e7eccfefd953dba9834b.js:1:4037
invokeTask@https://www.my-website.com/polyfills.e7eccfefd953dba9834b.js:1:9935
y@https://www.my-website.com/polyfills.e7eccfefd953dba9834b.js:1:23380
b@https://www.my-website.com/polyfills.e7eccfefd953dba9834b.js:1:23605
```

To check if Google Maps is loaded, I use the following method:

```
public async loadMapsAPI() {
        try {
            this.loadingMapsAPI = true;
            this.logger.info('Loading maps API...');
            await this.mapsAPILoader.load();
            this.loadingMapsAPI = false;
            return this.mapsAPILoaded = true;
        } catch (e) {
            this.loadingMapsAPI = false;
            return this.mapsAPILoaded = false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you know if the google map gets loaded at all when this happens? Or the map is rendered but just the markers do not appear on the map?

Comment: I added a piece of code to answer your question. I rely on the promise of the `MapsAPILoader.load()` being resolved. I only show the map if that resolves successfully.

Comment: I've checked the API documentation and found `mapReady()`, have you tried? Seems it can be used as callback when the map has fully loaded correctly. My guess is that, if makers fail, that callback won't be triggered. I can post an example if you find it useful.

Comment: Okay. I wrapped the `agm-markers` inside a `ng-template` with an `[ng-if]="mapIsReady"`. I'm setting `mapIsReady` when `agm-map` emits `(mapReady)`. I'll see if the errors keep happening.

Comment: Let's see. Hopefully that will help...

Comment: I was wondering if wrapping agm-markers with [ng-if]="mapIsReady" solved your problem. I get the same error logs.

Comment: I still get the error logs from time to time, but much less often, therefore I can't really tell if that was the right solution or not.

Comment: after digging my error logs I see that all coming from iOS and noticed other events of the same error are caused by being unable to load map itself and unable to register service worker. Could it be because of broken internet connection?

Comment: Seeing this as well. My monitoring also tells me that these errors come from Mobile Safari (16.3 & 16.4) on iPhone and Chrome Mobile WebView on Android (11).